# Is it possible to customize keyboard behaviour? Accented vowels as á and ñ

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

I am Spanish speaking, and own a US Macbook. So I would like to "spanishelize" my keyboard, namely:
pressing ' key just before a vowel to get a "é" text (meaning replace the "Control + e" combination for a just " ' " before the vowel)
pressing ~ key just befor n to get a "ñ" text (that means, replacing "option + n" for just the ~ key before the n)

Comment: I downloaded Ukelele, following other thread info, and succesfully duplicated U.S. keyboard, to a U.S.(mod) where I could make the above modifications, as wanted.

Comment: So post that as an answer, don't just leave it with some vague comment. Tell us what you did & how you made it work, otherwise it makes this entire Q&A totally useless.

Answer (score 3):

The Mac has what are known as 'dead keys' to add accents.
You access these by holding alt [option] whilst pressing one, then the next letter after that is given the accent.

They only work for commonly accented letters, not for instance trying to put a grave accent on a z, but for à é î ñ ü etc they're pretty nifty.

Unlike on Windows, where you have to work harder to *avoid* adding them by accident if you use the International English keyboard layout, this way you only get them when you actually *want* them.
Also, they are right there in your regular US English keyboard layout without having to switch to any special 'International' version.

The Keyboard viewer, available in the menu bar if you enable it in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard, will show you the dead keys highlighted in orange as you press alt [option]

[image]

& if you press one of these, when you release alt you will see which letters can accept that accent.

[image]

Once you get used to this, it's quick & easy & you won't need the keyboard viewer at all.

Mine is a UK ISO keyboard type, set to US for these pictures. Some keys will be in slightly different places on a US ANSI keyboard, but the general idea is the same.

There is an alternative way to do this on Mac. If you press & hold any accentable key, a small menu will pop up allowing you to choose from several accent types.
I can't demonstrate this as I have it completely disabled on my Mac. I hate it;) slow & irritating, & pops up when you don't want it to.
This way is quicker, easier to remember & never gets in your way.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I downloaded Ukelele*, following other thread info, and succesfully duplicated U.S. keyboard, to a U.S.(mod) where I could make the above modifications, as wanted, following the Ukelele manual, pretty simple, took me around 1 hour.
Hope this is usefull to someone else
*https://software.sil.org/ukelele/